# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown caret position

Tags: bootstrap-5

Is it possible in bootstrap 5 to right align the caret in the dropdown-menu items?
Moving as per this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Answering my own question. Use another class.

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle first-level-dropdown-toggle" href="#">Clouds</a>
  ...
</li>
```

And the class

```
.first-level-dropdown-toggle::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  margin-top: 0.7em;
}
```

[image]